# Kendo UI Grid Edit Template with AJAX call on change of DropdownList

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui

I have an MVC3 Webapp with Kendo UI Grid.
I am using the popup Template editing feature.
I have a DropdownList in the Template view.

Everything works great... Now I have added an `Instructions` div and a `Description` div that I want to use for instructions to the user, and the description of the selected item. These instructions depend upon the selected value of the Dropdown.
Upon selecting an item in the dropdown, I need to make an ajax call to the controller to get the instructions and the description for the selection.
I've tried a number of things but can't seem to get it to even fire off the call to the controller.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Murph

Here is the grid code:

```
@(Html.Kendo()
    .Grid<VW40.Web.Models.CompanyDefaultDataItemViewModel>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(c =>
    {
        c.ForeignKey(p => p.Type, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)@ViewBag.CompanyDefaultDataItemTypes, "CompanyDefaultDataItemTypeId", "Name").Title("Default Data Type").Width(200);
        c.Bound(p => p.Data);
        c.Bound(p => p.Instructions);
        c.Bound(p => p.Description);
        c.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); });
    })
    .ToolBar(t => t.Create())
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("CompanyDefaultDataItem").Window(w => w.Title("Add/Edit Company Default Data Item").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "width:100px;" })))
    .DataSource(ds => ds
        .Ajax()
        .Batch(false)
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Events(events => events.Error("error"))
        .Model(m => m.Id(p => p.CompanyDefaultDataItemId))
        .Read(read => read.Action("CompanyDefaultDataItems_Read", "Company", new { Id = @ViewBag.CompanyId }))
        .Update(update => update.Action("CompanyDefaultDataItem_Update", "Company"))
        .Create(update => update.Action("CompanyDefaultDataItem_Add", "Company", new { Id = ViewBag.CompanyId }))
        .Destroy(update => update.Action("CompanyDefaultDataItem_Delete", "Company"))
    )
)
```

And here is the Add/Edit Template and my attempt to do what I want in script:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@model VW40.Web.Models.CompanyDefaultDataItemViewModel

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CompanyId)
<br />
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Type, new { @id = "typeDropdown_Id" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type)
</div>
<br />

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Data)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Data, new { style = "width:250px" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Data)
</div>
<br />

<div style="padding-left:50px">Instructions:</div>
<div id="instructions" style="width:200px">
    @Model.Instructions
</div>
<br />

<div style="padding-left:50px">Description:</div>
<div id="description" style="width:200px">
    @Model.Description
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#typeDropdown_Id').click(function () {
            var typeId = $('#typeDropdown_Id option:slected').val();
            alert("selected type = " + typeId);
            $.getJSON("/Company/GetJsonCompanyDefaultDataItemTypeInstructionsAndDescription/" + typeId, function (data) {
                $('#instructions').val(data.Instructions);
                $('#description').val(data.Description);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Could you show the code for the dropdownlist?

Comment: var typeId = $('#typeDropdown_Id option:slected').val();

option:slected.. shouldn't it be 'selected' ?

Comment: @Tejo thanks...I corrected that but it still does not work. Perhaps it's something to do with how Kendo UI Grid handles the popup add/edit template. Maybe that's why the break point in the javascript code never happens.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do in my Template:

```
@Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.Type).BindTo(new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = "Type1" }, new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Type 2" } }, "Value", "Text")).Events(x => { x.Change("onTypeChange"); })

<script type="text/javascript">
        function onTypeChange(args) {
            var typeId = $('#type option:slected').val();
            alert("selected type = " + typeId);
            $.getJSON("/Company/GetJsonCompanyDefaultDataItemTypeInstructionsAndDescription/" + typeId, function (data) {
                $('#instructions').val(data.Instructions);
                $('#description').val(data.Description);
            });
        };
    </script>
```

See if it helps(sorry for the delay)

Comment: I'd access the value of the dropdown by using: $('#type').val()

Comment: @Tejo...Perhaps using the Kendo.DropDownListFor instead of the EditorFor control will work. Thanks, I'll give it a try. Remember though, this is in an Edit Template that the Kendo Grid loads into a popup window.

Comment: Yes, but I use it this way too. I've edited my answer now because i found a typo in my javascript